# I wonder if its a legit edit

Tags: discussion, editing

I wonder who would had accepted this edit suggestion,

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/43609/revisions

Question's title was

```
"How to display a filtered top-level document library in a subsite?"
```

changed to

```
Display a filtered top-level document library in a subsite?
```

Which makes no sense to me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with this:

From meta: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

> **4. Don't start with "How do I..."**
>
> Writing in that style ensures that you title will fail criteria 1-3, and get less attention than it deserves.
>
> This is a question site, and people will understand your titles are questions.

So yes... The common policy seems to indicate that a title shouldn't start with "How to" (but let me also say that I *may* have seen some contradiction on this, I seem to remember a post that encourage that format for comunity wiki question and such). So removing that should be good in the eye of <strike>Skeet</strike> the comunity.

Now... what about edits that only fix the "How To" in the title? **IMHO** that's another form of the edit farming that I was referencing in my other post ([Policy for minor edits that only remove "Thanks"](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/800/policy-for-minor-edits-that-only-remove-thanks)), so I would reject that as per Jeff suggestion (let only 2k+ users that *won't fill the queue* do such minor edits). Anyway seems that mods are fine with edits that only remove thanks, so I belive that the policy will be similar for "How To" only.

That said... I will skip similar reviews...

Comment: "The Eye of Skeet" should become a new saying... like "The Hand of God"... pretty much the same thing.

Comment: On a side note, while I was rejecting the suggested edits initially, I've been cleaning up the entirety of the post and unchecking "This edit was helpful" when the edit is too minor. That way the question still gets cleaned up (and gets cleaned up much more thoroughly), but there's no farming going on.

Comment: @rjcup3 ummm...this is *evil*. I like it ^_^, should start doing the same. Anyway, about the "Eye of Skeet"... I was thinking of something more like the Eye of Sauron...

Comment: *evil*? Don't give me that much credit. It's an effective solution to all problems involved.

Comment: @rjcup3 well... you still have the site benefit while killing the personal gain ^_^, so from the farmer point of view it *is* evil. That said... I approve that.